# ¿Error en contact form?

Tags: php, html

¿Cuál es el error en mi formulario? No llegan los correos pero aparece que sí me llegan, no bota ningún error la consola, todo sale perfecto.

Añadí código en JQUERY para que aparecieran algunas alertas pero nada más.

```
 <div class="form">
      <form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Tu Nombre*" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte su nombre">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Tu Email *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte su email.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Tu teléfono *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte un teléfono válido.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="¡Mándanos tu  mensaje!" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Porfavor inserte su mensaje."></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
               <!--<div class="primerBoton btn btn-primary btn-xl" id="sendMessageButton">
                <span class="segundoBoton">AÑADIR IMÁGENES</span>
                <input name="files[]" id="imagenes" type="file" placeholder="imágenes" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte archivos webp o PNG." multiple  class="btn tercerBoton btn-xl">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>-->
            </div> 
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
              <div id="success"></div>
              <button id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit">Enviar Mensaje</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Este es el PHP, todo está perfectamente vinculado, es un error de código, yo sé que debe ser algo relativamente sencillo, pero no llegan los mails, hice la configuración hace mucho tiempo ya.

Del código PHP solamente le moví la parte de arriba, no sé si deba añadir más variables pero no quiero dañar el código por añadir cosas.

```
<?php


/***************** Configuration *****************/

  // Replace with your real receiving email address
  $contact_email_to = "luiz_naiper@hotmail.com";



// Title prefixes
  $subject_title = "Mensaje de la página web:";
  $name_title = "Nombre:";
  $email_title = "Email:";
  $message_title = "Mensaje:";

  // Error messages
  $contact_error_name = "¡El nombre es muy corto!";
  $contact_error_email = "¡Por favor introduzca un email válido!";
  $contact_error_subject = "¡Por favor introduzca un teléfono válido!";
  $contact_error_message = "¡El mensaje es muy corto, por favor escriba algo 
   más.";

     /********** Do not edit from the below line ***********/

    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND 
   strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    die('Sorry Request must be Ajax POST');
  }

  if(isset($_POST)) {

$name = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$subject = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
$message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if(!$contact_email_to || $contact_email_to == 'contact@example.com') {
  die('The contact form receiving email address is not configured!');
}

if(strlen($name)<3){
  die($contact_error_name);
}

if(!$email){
  die($contact_error_email);
}

if(strlen($subject)<3){
  die($contact_error_subject);
}

if(strlen($message)<3){
  die($contact_error_message);
}

if(!isset($contact_email_from)) {
  $contact_email_from = "contactform@" . @preg_replace('/^www\./','', 
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
}

$headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $contact_email_from . '>' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$message_content = '<strong>' . $name_title . '</strong> ' . $name . '<br>';
$message_content .= '<strong>' . $email_title . '</strong> ' . $email . 
'<br>';
$message_content .= '<strong>' . $message_title . '</strong> ' . 
nl2br($message);

$sendemail = mail($contact_email_to, $subject_title . ' ' . $subject, 
$message_content, $headers);

if( $sendemail ) {
  echo 'OK';
} else {
  echo 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.';
    }
  }
?>
```

Lo único que cambié fueron algunos datos, se supone que debería haber servido normal, le añadí algunas funciones con JQUERY pero no sale.

Comment: Esto lo estas ejecutando en un entorno local o hosting?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, en hosting :) www.plusmarketing.com.mx

Comment: bueno, la mayoria de los proveedores tienen documentación de estos temas ya los hosting al no ser un servicio VPS tiene bloqueados los puertos de conexión entonces no permiten la conexión a SMTP de los correos electronicos, por el contrario usan la alternativa que estas usando actualmente sendmail de php, el tema con esto es que solo funcionara para los email que tengas configurados en la cuenta de hosting ya que para enviar un correo a nombre de @hotmail es necesario que te autentiques ante ellos ya que eso seria span no hay quien certifique ante los servidores que es una cuenta legal.

Comment: Gracias, realmente es un problema de código, ya que si no modifico nada del código anterior, sí me deja mandarlo con @hotmail.com sin problemas, es algo del código pero no encuentro la causa :(

Comment: ¿Revisaste la carpeta de SPAM?

Comment: Sí, no está tampoco, no encuentro mi error :(